# Post datas from distant file

Tags: file, curl

I know how to post data from a local file with curl :

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d @foo.txt http://bar.com/foobar
```

But I would like to do the same, but from a distant file, for example :

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d @http://www.google.fr/robots.txt http://bar.com/foobar
```

If I try this command, I have warnings : Couldn't read data from file, this makes an empty POST.

Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that my answer is not new for you, but why you can't do this:

```
curl http://www.google.fr/robots.txt > /tmp/foo.txt
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d @/tmp/foo.txt http://bar.com/foobar
```